How to add a custom sound to push notifications sent via Twilio API for iOS?
I'm using the Twilio API to send push notifications to iOS devices, and everything is working as expected. However, I would like to add a sound to the push notifications to get users' attention.
I've tried including different attributes in the payload, such as sound: "default" and specifying custom sound file names, but I haven't had any success getting the sound to play.
Here's an example of how I'm currently sending the notification to the Twilio server:
curl --location 'https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/{serviceId}/Entities/{identity}/Challenges' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {base64}' \
--data-urlencode 'FactorSid=${factorSid}' \
--data-urlencode 'Details.Message=Please verify login attempt'

Questions:

Is it possible to provide a custom sound to iOS users through the Twilio API?
Are there any additional steps I might be missing?
Is there specific documentation regarding sound handling for Twilio push notifications?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
